# Linear advance calibration technique

Tags: marlin, calibration, print-material

Marlin has a [Linear Advance calibration pattern generator](http://marlinfw.org/tools/lin_advance/k-factor.html), but I find it's hard to use because:

- It only prints the initial layer on the bed, where bed irregularities interfere with accurate reading of it.
- It doesn't do proper retraction and priming, so a mess of strings and underextruded initial segments/non-adhesion mess up the results.
- It's hard to visually evaluate.
- Getting a very wide range of K values involves multiple runs.
- It's hard to clean up.

Is there a better procedure for calibration of K value for linear advance?

Comment: Note that while this is a self-answer, I'm open to more/better answers too.

Answer (score 1):

The same effect as Marlin's test pattern, with alternation between fast and slow segments, can be achieved with a skewed tower and Cura's overhang settings, providing the opportunity to interactively adjust K value during the print, or insert changes at particular layers in the gcode for automated test towers.

I'm using the following OpenSCAD to make a skewed cylinder:

```
multmatrix(
   [[1,0,1/8,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1]])
cylinder(d=40,h=40);
```

with Cura set to:

- no top/bottom layers or infill
- single walls
- treat walls with 1° overhang as overhangs
- print overhangs at 25% speed

These values can of course be tuned, but the extreme low overhang angle and 8/1 slope is to prevent actual physical overhang-printing considerations from messing up the test.

Vase mode might work even better for this if it supports overhang settings, since it would avoid the layer seam.

Comment: Nice. I've been using the Marlin pattern in the past for Klipper's Pressure Advance, but there are some *really* disgusting features hidden in the g-code that's generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Klipper tuning tower and change the K value at each layer using Gcodes.
You can find the model here: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3957406

I find easier to see the best results this way, also you can test way more settings in a single run, while the Marlin pattern generator lets you test only few values at time.

Remember to print without infill.

[image]